# Grunt: Executing another command-line task while watch is running in background

Tags: vim, command-line, gruntjs

I am using [Gruntj](http://gruntjs.com) for automation in compiling less and coffescript files with [grunt-contirb-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-watch) plugin, i am also a command line user with  [vim](http://www.vim.org/) as a code editer. Always i write the code with vim, and when done i exit vim and go back to the terminal to run grunt watch plugin for compiling the files, and then exit watch and go back to vim again to edit the text.

So Is there any way to escape or suspend watch command-line sessions without terminating it and do some editing in vim within same terminal session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can execute external commands from within Vim: `:! grunt ...`; this blocks Vim until the command is done.
- If you need the original shell for command execution, you can `:suspend` Vim (also via `<C-Z>`), and then return to it from the original shell (after executing `grunt`) via `fg`.
- With a *terminal multiplexer* like `screen` or `tmux`, you can run both Vim and other shell(s) concurrently inside the same terminal. You'll find plenty of posts describing such setups.

Answer (score 3):

**The whole point of grunt-contrib-watch is to allow you to run your tasks in the background *without quitting your editor*.** So… you don't need to exit Vim at all.

You only need to start grunt in another terminal window or, if you use a terminal multiplexer, in another pane/window.